# Limit points and finding continous examples

Tags: real-analysis

1) a subset of R whose only limit point is 1? cannot think of a example, please help

2) f : [0, infinity) >>> R is continuous and bounded but fails to attain an absolute maximum? Does f(x) = x * sin(1/x) work ...the concern I have whether this is bounded or not?

3) f: [0, 4] >>> R satisfies lim x goes to 2 of f(x) = 0 and f(2) = 1
is  $$ f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
x-2 & \text{if} & x\in[0,4] \setminus\ 2\\
1 & \text{if} & 2
\end{array}
\right. $$

does this work?

Comment: On 2) it is ugly, and not defined at $0$. It is bounded, but does attain an absolute min. Try something simpler, such as $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Your third question is not understandable (to me). What's $n$ doing there? You need to give a more faithful reproduction of the real question.

Comment: isn't it 1/(1+x^2) attains absolute maximum at 0?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it asked for no absolute min. OK, $-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Or $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$. Or $1-e^{-x^2}$. Many others.

Comment: should be when x goes to 2.

Comment: Then your example is fine. If you want to use set-theoretic notation, it should be $[0,4]\setminus\{2\}$.

Comment: is it impossible for Q1?

Comment: Question $1$ is easy. Let $S$ consist of the points $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{3}{4}$, $\frac{7}{8}$, $\frac{15}{16}$, and so on. If you want the limit point of the set to b{ in the set (it need not be, and isn't in this case) throw $1$ into $S$.